# Disable regular advertising programmatically on CC2541 IC and advertise only by demand, is this possible?

Tags: c, bluetooth-lowenergy, firmware, texas-instruments

I just want to find out if CC2541 BLE device can be in sleep mode and wake up only when it is scanned by an observer device. Meaning it does not advertise data during sleep mode, but only respond when scanned using specific UUIDs. Is this possible? Is it also possible to wake it up for regular advertising and turn it back to sleep mode again using UUIDs while scanning? Thanks in advance.

Comment: All pairing functionalities is a part of GAP, not GATT. GATT is used for data communication between two BLE devices. I have worked with CC2541 for a while but didn't consider your statement. Where did you get that information from, any source ?.

Comment: I just corrected my question above. I did not used CC2541 before and in my application I do not need to advertise regularly but only need to respond from scan that is using specific UUID. That is why I asked this question. Thanks for responding early.

Answer (score 1):

CC2541 BLE device can be in sleep mode and wake up,and can wake it up for regular advertising and turn it back to sleep mode again.But not by "it is scanned by an observer device".

When in sleep mode,it can't [be] scan[ned].So you can only use a sleep timer or interrupt to wake it up.

Thank you.

Best Regards,

Viki Shi
TEXAS INSTRUMENTS

Comment: maybe it doesn't count as "sleep mode", but can't you listen for active scans and only reply with ad packets after detecting an active scan?

Answer (score 0):

You can only read the device name and device address for CC2541 without pairing, since it only advertises with those information. All other information has to be accessed over GATT, such as the accelerometer data, battery data and data from the other sensors.

Comment: What is your point ?. From 28:50, the limit of how many peripherals you can connect to is explained, and this is not our case ?.

Comment: I'm sorry, but seems you do not know that you can acquire data, not only device name and address, if you parse the scanRecord or the 31 byte payload, and you do not need to connect or pair to them. That is why we have beacons. If you read and watch carefully you will find-out.

Comment: If you download the android code of that video and try to read it you will find out.

Comment: Sorry but you were referring to CC2541 and I thought you meant following device: 

http://www.ti.com/tool/cc2541dk-mini

and this is definately not a beacon. Did you mean CC2541 SensorTag and use the beacon capabilities ?. You did not mention any beacon in your question.

Comment: I am refering to the IC itself.

Comment: If we're talking about the same device (CC2540 Keyfob, the one in the link), then you cannot compare it to the device in the video, since they are showing the capabilities of a beacon and CC2541 Keyfob is NOT a beacon. A beacon might advertises with the device data, but CC2541 Keyfob doesn't.